# How do I interpret $\lim_{k \to \infty} \inf \{ s > 0 : \int_0^s g(x) \, dx > k\}$? (plus related question)

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let $t_k = \inf \{ s > 0 : \int_0^s g(x) \, dx > k\}$

**Problem 1:** How should I interpret $\lim_{k \to \infty} t_k$? Is it $\inf \{ s > 0 : \int_0^s g(x) \, dx = \infty\}$?

**Problem 2:** Assuming that $t = \inf \{ s > 0 : \int_0^s g(x) \, dx = \infty \}$, can we deduce that $\int_0^t g(x) \, dx < \infty$?

**Attempt problem 2:** Since $t = \inf \{ s > 0 : \int_0^s g(x) \, dx = \infty \}$, this means that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, we have that $\int_0^{t-\varepsilon} g(x) \, dx < \infty$, otherwise $t$ would not be the infimum. Since this holds for all $\varepsilon > 0$, we must have that $\int_0^t g(x) \, dx < \infty$ (I'm unsure if this holds in the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity $t_k = \inf \{ s > 0 : \int_0^s g(x) \, dx > k\}$ depends on what number $k$ is. The expression $\lim_{k\to\infty} t_k$ should be interpreted as the limit of a function of $k,$ defined just as any limit is defined.

Now imagine, for example, theat $g(x) = e^{-x}.$ Then $\int_0^s g(x)\,ds = 1 - e^{-x} < 1.$ No matter how big $s$ gets, the integral will never be $+\infty.$ Therefore the set $\{ s > 0 : \int_0^s g(x) \, dx = \infty\}$ will be empty. The infimum of the empty set is $+\infty.$